# How to replace one of the row with one of the column in dataframe Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a quick question. I am trying to convert dataframe to different dataframe. Would it be possible if you can help me? I am showing the input and output as follow? My current dataframe described as input and what i want to see is in output. Please see it  is in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYvHd.png)

Comment: Hi. Please post your dataframe input and output as text, not as image. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: [Pandas101](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html) has an entire section dedicated to data reshaping and pivoting. What have you tried? Why did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly very simple with a pivot table:

```
df.pivot_table(index='date_year', columns='name')
```